# Ubuntu 12.x on HP Pavilion g6-1d21dx

Tags: amd-processor

What would it take to ensure that Ubuntu 12.x is supported seamlessly on

> HP Pavilion g6-1d21dx with AMD A6 APU and Radeon HD 6520G

Comment: Buy HP, or, at least, get a high ranked job at the company.

Answer (score 1):

Why not download a liveCD and see how it handles? That's really one of the easiest ways to find out.

That said, generally speaking, the only issue I've ever run into when it comes to compatibility/support is in the graphics cards. I've found driver support for cutting-edge ATI/AMD video cards to be sketchy, but that's been a while (I generally use Nvidia cards, because I'm pragmatic, and I've had good experiences with their proprietary drivers). However, a quick Google search for the card in your laptop [brings up this chart](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device/Radeon%20HD%206520G), which suggests that it shouldn't be an issue, just make sure you keep your drivers up to date.

Also, generally speaking, the most recent versions of Ubuntu are widely supported. At this point, things have matured to the point that most systems are supported out of the box, or with just a little bit of configuring. So you're pretty often in the clear. As I said earlier, though, when in doubt, toss in a live CD and see how it handles (keeping in mind, of course, that the live CD will be slower than an installed copy).