# Heating, projecting and lid closing problems in Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: 15.04, power-management, overheating

Ever since I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 in April this year, I have been beset by productivity-reducing problems. I had started off [unable to get the login screen on booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615861/black-screen-on-upgrading-to-15-04) which got resolved about a month and a half later when I installed some updates.

My latest set of problems though don't seem to go away.

1. Heating: I've installed tlp, but the bottom of my laptop can fry an egg. A couple of times, the machine just froze and I had to change its seating on my table with more circulation underneath before rebooting. In Windows, the machine works fine.
2. Closing the lid: This results in the machine shutting down. On re-opening the lid, it boots up automatically. I've tried the different options that tweak offers. Currently I'm set to Suspend when Laptop Lid closes.
3. Projecting: The machine fails to recognise a projector or an external monitor. Nothing happens when I press the projection button on my keyboard. When I rebooted into Windows, I was able to project using the same projector.

I hope these can all be clubbed into one post since I believe they may be related.My machine is a HP Pavilion g6 with AMD Quad-Core A6-3420M with Radeon 6520G graphics card, which could be a minority configuration as far as Ubuntu is concerned, but is significant for a user.

Comment: Meanwhile, I discovered other problems. If I run Kazam to record a video, I cannot go and save my video because there is no System Tray with the Kazam Icon! It gets more and more weird. I must confess that for a recent convert to Ubuntu, I am fed up with the 15.04 version. It is only the desire to avoid Windows that keeps me here, but to be honest, Windows was working without any of these problems. What are my options now? Wait for another three weeks, upgrade to 15.10 and then start the theatrics all over again.  At this point, I am certainly frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer 
[Ubuntu 12.x on HP Pavilion g6-1d21dx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198859/ubuntu-12-x-on-hp-pavilion-g6-1d21dx) and as suggested, the way now would be to try using a Live CD both 15.10 Ubuntu Gnome and 15.04/15.10 Ubuntu (standard version with Unity) and to see if these problems get resolved in any of these versions.

Refer [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) on installation notes. It does not cover 15.04 at this moment.

The link below shows how to install proprietary binary drivers as well.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD?action=show&redirect=BinaryDriverHowto%2FATI